# loading another form using eventhandler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, thread-safety

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p1 = new Process();
    p1.StartInfo.FileName
        = @"D:\Softwares\ftrScanApiEx_v3.2\ftrScanApiEx_v3.2\ftrScanApiEx.exe";
    p1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p1.Exited += new EventHandler(p1_Exited);
    p1.Start();
}

private void p1_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Form3 is not loading even there is no error  ..  any idea why ???

Comment: Does the process really exits?

Comment: I'm guessing it may have something to do with threading.  There is no guarantee that p1_Exited is getting called on your GUI thread (it's most likely not).  Try using invoke in that event to call the Hide and Show methods.

Comment: @NathanA You're right but that should throw `InvalidOperationException` isn't it? I guess process doesn't exited at all

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yeah i checked it.. its exiting

Comment: @Legend Does the Exited event got fired?

Comment: actually its loading the form3 aswell but due to some reason it unable to load the content of it..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yup but it unable to load contents

Comment: I'm confused. In your question `Form3 is not loading even there is no error .. any idea why ???` but in your comment `actually its loading the form3 aswell but due to some reason it unable to load the content of it`. What's the problem actually?

Comment: You may need to use `this.Invoke` since Exited event will be fired in other thread. Try that.

Comment: The problem is my code is working properly and its also opening form 3  but form 3 contain some controls like text box , label , picturebox etc which its not loading .. it just processing processing showing no result..

Comment: Go with the threading idea.  It's worth a shot.  You are creating the new form on an unknown thread, and that causes all sorts of hard to diagnose problems.

Comment: I think it's not throwing exceptions because this new form isn't owned by any parent form handle from your application loop. Therefore it's legal for it to be shown in the threading context it's called. The reason it doesn't stay open is probably because the calling thread is ending. Any gurus out there feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, as indicated in the running comments, that this is indeed a threading issue. Invoke to the UI thread before creating Form3. Check the [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Invoke

```
private void p1_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(OnProcessExited));
    }
    else
    {
        OnProcessExited();
    }
}

private void OnProcessExited()
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```